# CommandBar is always visible in portrait mode with windows 10 universal app

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I don't know if I'm missing something but I doubt it, and to me it looks more like a bug, but I thought I'd check here first just in case.

This is the code I have:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar x:Name="bottomAppBar"
                Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}" 
                Visibility="Collapsed" 
                IsOpen="False" 
                ClosedDisplayMode="Compact" 
                IsSticky="False">
        <AppBarButton x:Name="btnSearch" Label="Search" 
         Icon="Find" Foreground="White" />
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

When displayed in portrait mode on my phone, it always shows the command bar and when I rotate my phone (landscape), it hides it ok.

Strangely enough the XAML Editor always shows the command bar, no matter what orientation the editor is set to.

This problem occurs on both the emulator and the actual phone.

I haven't tried it via code-behind yet as I'm using MVVM and I'd like to bind a property to the Visibility or the IsOpen properties but will try it later and if required, I will but hopefully, it won't come down to this.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Thierry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this code in the Windows 10 Mobile emulator build 10586. The command bar is not display in portrait and landscape.

Comment: Thanks for the update & taking the time to try it. I will check my emulator build later as when I rotate the mobile UI is messed up. By messed up I mean, it is displaying the phone UI in portrait but using 1/3 of the landscape visible area. This however works when I use the version using 3G of RAM but often causes an out of memory on my SP3 (i7 with 8GB).

Comment: Hi Danvy, you are correct. it does work and I feel like a complete idiot. I created a new empty UWP project and it worked immediately, so I started to add all my namespace to the mainpage.xaml and still worked. I decided to remove the CommandBar from my project and this is when I spotted the issue! I should have done this in the first place! My VisualStateManager node was collapsed and didn't spot that I had a test line to hide my command bar in portrait mode! So annoyed and so sorry for wasting your time. Anyway, problem solved which is the main thing.

Comment: Great news that there's a solution to your problem. Feel free to check the answer to close this case ;)